# Manual Data flag in Google Fit Android API?

Tags: android, api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Does the Google Fit API provide any flag to indicate the data was entered manually in the app.If yes, please suggest which needs to checked for that as the requirement is to process only the device collected data and not the manual entries in fitness apps.

Comment: Its old question. If you got any ans for this, please share

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score -1):

Closest you can get to achieve is this to filter out the results provided by the google fit sdk based on the original data source attributes. 
For example

```
dataset.dataPoints.forEach { 
                    it.originalDataSource.appPackageName
                    it.originalDataSource.device
                    it.originalDataSource.name
}
```